# Did the psychic Sonja Grace find the body of Austin David King?

Tags: psychics

There are many reports on the internet covering how the psychic Sonja Grace found the body of a missing boy 10 miles from his home.

e.g. [TDN Daily News](http://tdn.com/news/state-and-regional/article_85c4cc6c-94ed-11df-8c2e-001cc4c002e0.html)

I've not seen any skeptical reports about it. Are there any?

Comment: even a blind squirrel finds a nut once in a while.

Comment: I couldn't locate anything about this specific event, there is plenty out there about general debunking of psychics, including supposedly finding lost kids.

Comment: A couple of notable failures: 
http://www.centerforinquiry.net/blogs/entry/another_abduction_rape_highlights_glaring_failure_of_psychic_detectives/

Comment: Story about 80 different "psychic tips" called in for a case of missing girls. “They are all giving their opinion,” Chief Deputy Rick Abben said, “No two are having the same vision I guess you could say.” And you can bet if one of those 80 guesses is even close, they'll claim success!
http://freethoughtblogs.com/dispatches/2012/07/30/psychics-give-tips-on-missing-girls/

Comment: The article doesn't say that Sonja Grace 'found' the body. Even by the best interpretation she recommended a logging road as a place to search. Logging roads are generally very long, so she wasn't being very specific.